# how to apply a formula in one cell to the entire column

Tags: vba

*Column E   Column F*
*Start_Time*       *End_Time*
12:16:56    12:16:57
12:16:57    12:16:59
12:18:50    12:19:04
***12:20:13 12:20:13***
12:20:32    12:20:33
12:20:42    12:20:49
12:31:16    12:31:17
12:37:32    12:37:47
12:45:41    12:45:43
**12:48:36  12:48:36**
12:48:44    12:48:46

I want to do if the end time is equal to the start time, use the previous end time as the start time. For example, in the picture ***if E5=F5, then E5=F4.*** I used this common,it works but only in the specific cell.  How can I apply it to the whole column? I tried If...then...statement as following, not works.Thanks.

```
For i = 2 To lastrow - 1

  If Range("E3").Value = Range("F3").Value Then
     Range("E3").Value = Range("F2").Value
   End If
Next i
```

Expected output:

*Column E   Column F*
*Start_Time*       *End_Time*
12:16:56    12:16:57
12:16:57    12:16:59
12:18:50    **12:19:04**
***12:19:04 12:20:13***
12:20:32    12:20:33
12:20:42    12:20:49
12:31:16    12:31:17
12:37:32    12:37:47
12:45:41    **12:45:43**
**12:45:43  12:48:36**
12:48:44    12:48:46

Answer (score 1):

```
For i = 2 To lastrow - 1
  If Range("E" & i+1).Value = Range("F" & i+1).Value Then
     Range("E" & i+1).Value = Range("F" & i).Value
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: @PhoenixNing If this worked and is the method by which you solved your problem mark it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It will reward lbo and yourself as well as remove it from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1):

No Loop needed:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
    .Range("E3:E" & lastrow - 1).Value = _
        .Evaluate("IF(E3:E" & lastrow - 1 & " = F3:F" & lastrow - 1 & ",F2:F" & _
        lastrow - 2 & ",E3:E" & lastrow - 1 & ")")
End With
```